# What is the best way to copy 1000 pics from my PC to my ipad3?

Tags: windows, photos, data-transfer, ipad, file-transfer

I don't want to copy all of my pictures and i dont want to setup ongoing sync.  I simply want to do a one time transfer of pictures in a certain folder from my windows PC to iPad

Answer (score 1):

This [TC Geeks article](http://www.tcgeeks.com/how-to-transfer-files-with-your-ipad-ftp-wireless-bluetooth/) describes several ways to access files on your iPad, using FTP or Bluetooth.  You'll need an FTP server- or server-capable app on the PC side; there are many.  The article is old - check current prices.  The first iPad app described is currently (9/1/12) available at a hefty discount, f/ex.